# why does this js function cause a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I dont't understand how this code causes the memory leak.

```
var theThing = null;
var replaceThing = function () {
    var originalThing = theThing;
    var unused = function () {
        if (originalThing)
            console.log("hi");
    };
    theThing = {
        longStr: new Array(1000000).join('*'),
        someMethod: function () {
            console.log(someMessage);
        }
    };
};
setInterval(replaceThing, 1000);
```

If I set `originalThing` to be null at the end of the function `replaceThing`, everything will be fine. But I didn't see a reference loop here and I don't know why these closure cannot be released.

And doesn't v8 GC use mark sweep? If I put these code into IIFE, the memory leak still exists. But how can the root context reach these variables and functions?
I used chrome to test these code.Now I'm confused about how GC works on Closure.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/

> Because the inner function holds a reference to the outer function's variables, the scope object...will not be garbage collected.

Comment: Do you mean that `someMessage` is not found?But I have tried to replace it  to a string `'someMessage'`.The memory leak still exists

Comment: Thanks,I got it, but I still have some questions.First,I understand how the deeply-nested context comes into being, but why this context cannot be released,since in the first context, `originalThing` equals to null, and if `theThing` is not global, after I call `replaceThing`,`theThing` won't be used anymore which should be fired with `someMethod`.Second, when I delete the `unused`, the leak seems to be gone.

Comment: I found a good resource (scroll down to closures): https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak

Comment: I saw this sentence, but I think it a conclusion of the listing 4.In listing 4, the inner function has been returned.`x` holds the reference of the inner function, while the inner function holds the `a` of the outer function, so when the outer function finished, the scope object still live in the memory.But what happened after `x('inner x')`,if `x` is not global, all these are unreachable at last.

Answer (score 0):

after the first call where `originalThing` is assigned null, `theThing` becomes a reference to the new object, and the second and subsequent calls `originalThing` assign a reference to object, and then again `theThing` becomes a reference to the new object, but `originalThing` will link to the previous object

Comment: yes, but why cannot these variables be fired.if the GC use mark sweep, and all these cannot be reached

Comment: because one reference to object remains

Comment: but what if the object which holds the reference to the object1 is not needed anymore?Let's assume, obj1,obj2, the next one holds the previous one, obj2 cannot be fired because of obj1, but if obj1 is also not needed, all these should be fired. The first `originalThing` is null, the next one holds the reference of the previous one, but when the last one is not needed anymore, why aren't they be fired.Did I misunderstand what you mean?

Comment: well, let's order. We have declared the variable outside `theThing` Then we create a function inside the `replaceThing` and created `originalThing` a link to the outside `theThing`. Then we create a `unused` where `...if (originalThing)...`=> reference to` theThing` further change `theThing` link to a new object, but remains within the` unused` link to the previous object `theThing`, although we will lose and the context as well as the object outside the `replaceThing` GC  not clean `unused` after complete `replaceThing`